# pyautocad: COM Error: (-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', (None, None, None, 0, None))

Tags: python, autocad

I have issue with python autocad

The error is "COM Error: (-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', (None, None, None, 0, None))"

I request you all to get the solution for this problem

My code is:

```
import pyautocad
from pyautocad import APoint
import comtypes


acad = pyautocad.Autocad()



# Define the points for a rectangle
#points = [APoint(0, 0), APoint(10, 0), APoint(10, 5), APoint(0, 5)]

# Create a lightweight polyline from the points
#polyline = acad.model.AddLwpolyline(points)

# Specify the pick point as an APoint
pick_point = APoint(5, 2.5)

# Attempt to create a hatch
try:
    hatch = acad.model.AddHatch(0, pick_point, "SOLID", 1.0)  # Adjust the scale factor as needed

    hatch.Evaluate()
 
except comtypes.COMError as e:
    print(f"COM Error: {e}")
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-BAF2BEDD-489A-42D1-92B1-698DC9DAE675), Hatch does not take a point as an argument.

First create the hatch, then append the outer loop

Or use SendCommand